# Electron SQL security

Tags: javascript, php, electron

I have a rather noob question that I can't seem to find the answer for. So I've heard that all electron apps can be turned into source code and then manipulated. So that leads me to my next question. If I'm connecting to a SQL database then what is keeping people from viewing source code, going in and doing whatever they want to the db? I mean once they see the source code the username and password are right there...Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm thinking of making something on electron that needs decent security. I've also heard php cannot be used. So... Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm just wondering because Discord, whatsapp and such seem to do it somehow, but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, any information in any application can be reverse engineered, so I would suggest to not hardcode database passwords or any other critical credentials.

I assume Slack, Discord and others don't hardcode their DB passwords in app. Their desktop app don't "talk" directly to database, it's talking with some server-side application. You as a user have to provide credentials to your account. Communication is done through API which implies various restrictions based on your user privileges. This server-side application decides what you can and what you cannot do and translates your requests into DB operations.

So using those apps you don't go even near to their DB passwords.

If you want to do client application which should be able to do some operations on DB, I would suggest the same, split this application into two parts: ClientApp and ServerApp.